# Init IOS project with pods using react-native init command

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to create the IOS project with pods using react-native init command?

Currently there is different installation instruction for react native libraries.
Example: Some of them install using react-native link command while other requires to setup using cocoapods. Missing both will leads to lots of compilation errors.

Could anyone suggest what is best way to create project using react-native.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the official react native documentation, there are 2 ways to start up your project, which is using 'CRNA' or 'Build With Native Code'.

For CRNA, it is the fastest and easiest way to start up your project.
It really easy to run your React Native app on a physical device without setting up a development environment. If you want to run your app on the iOS Simulator or an Android Virtual Device, please refer to the instructions for building projects with native code to learn how to install Xcode and set up your Android development environment.

The react native link is used if you want to link your library through the terminal. But in some cases, there are several problem occurred related to library compatibility. I rather suggest use pods or manually link your library through XCode.

Pods is a dependency manager for native code that we use on our native code project. It will automatically generate and link the library.

If you want to have pods on your ios project. After you install cocoapods, you could follow these steps :

```
1. Open terminal and direct to your project (cd YOUR_PROJECT/ios 
2. pod init
3. And then Podfile will be generated within the ios project.
```

And from now on, you should use YOUR_PROJECT.xcworkspace if you want to manage the project. Thats because Pods should be placed and included same with your project but '.xcodeproj' does not include your Pods.